System.DmlException: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION Error on ConvertLead - Invalid Formula
I’m encountering the following error when trying to convert a lead in Salesforce:
System.DmlException: ConvertLead failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, Validation error on Account: Validation Formula "Core_Account_English_Only_Name" Invalid (Cannot invoke "common.udd.EnumInfo.getAllEnumItems()" because "enumInfo" is null): []

Here’s what I’ve observed:

The error happens during the lead conversion process and points to a validation rule called Core_Account_English_Only_Name on the Account object.
The error mentions EnumInfo.getAllEnumItems(), but we aren’t directly using EnumInfo.getAllEnumItems() anywhere in our org (neither in the validation rule nor in any code).
The validation rule itself involves a formula, but we cannot find any explicit references to EnumInfo in it.

What I’ve already tried:

Reviewed the Validation Rule: I checked the Core_Account_English_Only_Name validation rule, but it does not seem to contain any direct or indirect references to EnumInfo.
Checked for Triggers or Apex Code: I also verified whether there are any triggers or Apex code that could be invoking this method, but I didn't find anything.

Any help or insights into what could be causing this error would be greatly appreciated. Could this be a hidden reference to EnumInfo in a formula? How can I further troubleshoot this issue?
Thank you!

can you edit question and share your formula for Core_Account_English_Only_Name ?
